# DataNitro - limit on how many CellRanges you can add?

Tags: datanitro

I'm trying to accumulate CellRanges that meet certain condition so that I can set a property on that entire range in one go

```
rng=None
for c in Cell(1,1).vertical_range:
    if c.value and c.value.endswith(' Total'):
        rng=rng+c.horizontal_range if rng is not None else c.horizontal_range
rng.font.bold=True
```

I'm getting error below for ranges accumulating more 30 areas or so. It's not always the same number of areas that cause the error. So I can't put my finger on a specific limit. I do use a work around whereby I set the desired property on the range after say 20 areas were accumulated and then reset the CellRange but it would be good to be able to accumulate all the areas I need subject to whatever contrains on the number of areas excel has

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "27/scriptStarter.py", line 128, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\xxxx\rangebug.py", line 3, in <module>
    rng=rng+c.horizontal_range if rng is not None else c.horizontal_range
  File "27/basic_io.py", line 546, in __add__
  File "27/basic_io.py", line 465, in __init__
  File "27/basic_io.py", line 1022, in _cell_name_parser
  File "27/basic_io.py", line 1136, in _named_range_parser
  File "27/iron.py", line 139, in getNamedRange
  File "27/dnparser.py", line 95, in checkForErrors
dntypes.NitroException: Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in our software - we'll look into it and release a fix.

In the meantime, you could do this:

```
for c in Cell(1,1).vertical_range:
    if c.value and c.value.endswith(' Total'):
        c.horizontal_range.font.bold=True
```